# Weird issue with UserVoice & Web Fonts randomly not displaying

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, uservoice

I have a site that makes use of web fonts & obviously `@font-face`; I recently added the UserVoice widget JavaScript call to the header of the site and I"m not 100% sure if it's what is causing the issue, but a couple times since I have added that some parts of the text don't show up (and no fallback font is shown either), it's just blank.

It seems to be only the odd occasion it happens, but of all the times I have viewed the site I have only noticed it *after* adding the UserVoice widget.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? The site is located at: http://www.gimko.com.au/

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce his problem, which browser are you on? In Chrome, for example, I'm getting quite a many JavaScript errors in inspector Console, so I would start by trying to fix those first. Maybe removing one integration at a time and trying if the problem persists would help tracking down the problem. Sometimes moving the problematic JavaScript code in the end of the body might help, so you can try that too.

Comment: My main browser I use is FF, which is what I have seen it in.

Comment: Can you specify the exact text that is disappearing from the page? I tried with Firefox 21 and didn't see the problem occurring.

Comment: Hmmmm..... I haven't seen the problem since, could be because the fonts are now cached, not sure.... but the text was the header menu text on the left nav. Sports Cards, Gaming Cards etc